# How to exec tons of Insert queries read from file in Sqlite Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

Currently I have a requirement in which I need to read tons of insert queries approx 100 000 queries written in a .sql file. I need to read this file from SdCard and update the local sqlite database in my application.

I am using below code with successful update:

At the same time I am worried about the performance issue and risk of application hang when it will be like a task of heavier sql file. Do I need to change the approach what I am using right now? Is there any better implementation with Sqlite Database to perform this task with no risk.

```
/* Iterate through lines (assuming each insert has its own line 
   and theres no other stuff) */
while (insertReader.ready()) {
    String insertStmt = insertReader.readLine();
    db.execSQL(insertStmt);

    bytesRead += insertStmt.length();
    int percent = (int) (bytesRead * 100 / totalBytes);

    // To show the updating data progress
    if (previousPercent < percent) {
        System.out.println(percent);
        previousPercent = percent;
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_PROGRESS_PERCENT, percent);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setData(b);
        errorViewhandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    result++;
}
insertReader.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that the fastest way to import a lot of data into your database is to use `applyBatch()` on a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#applyBatch(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)).

Here is an example I reduced from one of my projects:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> cpoList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

while (condition) {
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder b = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(YourOwnContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
    b.withYieldAllowed(true);

    b.withValue(COLUMN_ONE, 1);
    b.withValue(COLUMN_TWO, 2);

    cpoList.add(b.build());

    // You could check here, whether you have a lot of items in your list already. If you do, you should send them to applyBatch already.
}

if(cpoList.size() > 0) {
    context.get().getContentResolver().applyBatch(YourOwnContentProvider.AUTHORITY, cpoList);
}
```

As an example implementation of applyBatch:

```
@Override
public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations) {
    ContentProviderResult[] result = new ContentProviderResult[operations.size()];
    int i = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();

    sqlDB.beginTransaction();

    try {
        for (ContentProviderOperation operation : operations) {
            result[i++] = operation.apply(this, result, i);
        }

        sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // Deal with exception
    } finally {
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems promising but i am not clear with EPGContentprovider and it's implementation. Would i be able to hit insert queries that i've to read from a File located in SdCard.

Comment: That ContentProvider is actually my ContentProvider from the code I pasted in. You need to make your own content provider in this case.

Comment: And yes, you can add insert new rows from any source. So File will work too. You just need to parse the File piece by piece in the while loop.